# Get to a function on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to get to a function on a fragment.

Please look at the function msgFromTopFragment at main activity.

The declaration of bottomFragment results in an error message – incompatible types.

And I can’t understand why. How can I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements TopFragment.onBtnListener{

    TopFragment topFragment = new TopFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }//onCreate

    @Override
    public void msgFromTopFragment(String msg) {
        BottomFragment buttomFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
        buttomFragment.updateResult(msg);
    }//msgFromTopFragment
}//MainActivity
```

Code for bottom fragment:

```
public class BottomFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView resultTv;

    public BottomFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);
        resultTv = view.findViewById(R.id.resultTv);

        return view;
    }

    public void updateResult(String msg){
        resultTv.setText(msg);
    }
}//BottomFragment
```

Comment: We can't see the errors add more explanation & error with image.

Comment: If you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you might want to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead

Comment: What do you want to do, is you want to pass value from fragment to activity ? or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

BottomFragment buttomFragment = (BottomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFrag‌​ment);

this solved it :) thank you